# Angular acceleration affect on accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, gyroscope, kinematics

In the [sensor documentation of android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html) it is given that accelerometer measures linear acceleration + gravity

So in my problem I formuled accelerometer readings as

Accelerometer = Linear Acceleration + Gravity + Noise

But I wonder should I consider the effect of angular/rotational acceleration, also in that simply calculating angular acceleration with the help of gyroscope is enough or not.

So should I use

Accelerometer = Linear Acceleration + Gravity + Angular Acceleration + Noise

Comment: Have a look at using the geomagnetic field sensor in combination with the accelerometer to determine a device's position relative to the magnetic north pole (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html), and use this information to calculate angular acceleration (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_acceleration).

Comment: I already read it, there is no information about this

Comment: I would start by dumping the TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR to a log, or better yet console, and see what values display (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR). Your going to need some numerical equations for angular acceleration to plug this input into **http://physics.tutorvista.com/motion/angular-acceleration.html** **http://www.softschools.com/formulas/physics/angular_acceleration_formula/153/**